# Docker container is missing files when using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-volume

I want to create docker-compose setup with 2 containers.

1. A MariaDB Container
2. A Moodle container based on bitnami/moodle:latest

These containers should be used for testing custom PHP plugins for Moodle WebServices. To do so I have to copy the newest version of my plugin code to the location `/bitnami/moodle/local/local_custom_api/`

I did this in the `Dockerfile`

```
FROM bitnami/moodle:latest

COPY ./local_custom_api/ /bitnami/moodle/local/local_custom_api/
```

And then I created the following `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb
    volumes:
      - D:\\Docker\\Moodle\\Database:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=moodle
      - MYSQL_ROOT_USER=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=moodle

  moodle:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 8443:8443
    environment:
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_HOST=mariadb
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_USER=root
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_PASSWORD=moodle
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_NAME=moodle
    volumes:
      - D:\\Docker\\Moodle\\Moodle:/bitnami/moodle
      - D:\\Docker\\Moodle\\MoodleData:/bitnami/moodledata
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    links:
      - mariadb:mariadb
```

This works fine and both containers are created and the moodle install script completes successfully but the copy cmd in the Dockerfile does not work. The files do not show up in the specified volume.

After some research, it seems that I have to use named volumes to make the copy cmd work (don't really know why). So I created named volumes but now the moodle install process cannot find a file although I just changed the host path of the volume

Here is the new `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb
    volumes:
      - moodle_db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=moodle
      - MYSQL_ROOT_USER=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=moodle
  moodle:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 8443:8443
    environment:
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_HOST=mariadb
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_USER=root
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_PASSWORD=moodle
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_NAME=moodle
    volumes:
      - moodle_app:/bitnami/moodle
      - moodle_data:/bitnami/moodledata
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    links:
      - mariadb:mariadb

volumes:
  moodle_db:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: "D:\\Docker\\Moodle\\Database"
      o: bind
    name: moodle_db
  moodle_app:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: "D:\\Docker\\Moodle\\Moodle"
      o: bind
    name: moodle_app
  moodle_data:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: "D:\\Docker\\Moodle\\MoodleData"
      o: bind
    name: moodle_data
```

This is the output. The install always crashes and the only files in the moodle_app volume are the plugin files that were copied successfully:

```
moodle-test-moodle-1   | moodle 16:04:14.05 
moodle-test-moodle-1   | moodle 16:04:14.05 Welcome to the Bitnami moodle container
moodle-test-moodle-1   | moodle 16:04:14.05 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/containers
moodle-test-moodle-1   | moodle 16:04:14.05 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/containers/issues
moodle-test-moodle-1   | moodle 16:04:14.05 
moodle-test-moodle-1   | moodle 16:04:14.05 INFO  ==> ** Starting Moodle setup **
moodle-test-moodle-1   | realpath: /bitnami/apache/conf: No such file or directory
moodle-test-moodle-1   | moodle 16:04:14.08 INFO  ==> Configuring Apache ServerTokens directive
moodle-test-moodle-1   | moodle 16:04:14.10 INFO  ==> Configuring PHP options
moodle-test-moodle-1   | moodle 16:04:14.10 INFO  ==> Setting PHP expose_php option
moodle-test-moodle-1   | moodle 16:04:14.12 INFO  ==> Validating settings in MYSQL_CLIENT_* env vars
moodle-test-moodle-1   | moodle 16:04:14.13 INFO  ==> Validating settings in POSTGRESQL_CLIENT_* env vars
moodle-test-moodle-1   | moodle 16:04:14.19 INFO  ==> Restoring persisted Moodle installation
moodle-test-moodle-1   | moodle 16:04:16.25 INFO  ==> Trying to connect to the database server
moodle-test-moodle-1   | grep: /opt/bitnami/moodle/config.php: No such file or directory
moodle-test-moodle-1 exited with code 2
```

How can the host location affect the internal functionality of the container?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, in the docker compose, you are bind mounting to the parent directory of the directory that has been copied in the docker file. [The docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#mount-into-a-non-empty-directory-on-the-container) says: if a container directory is non-empty it is hidden behind the contents of a bind-mounted directory (i.e. you can't initialize the host directory with a container files there in this way). Therefore your copy at `/bitnami/moodle/local/local_custom_api/` (in container) is hidden instead the directory is the same as `D:\Docker\Moodle\Moodle`

```yaml
# ...
volumes:
  - D:\\Docker\\Moodle\\Moodle:/bitnami/moodle # -> everything in the `/bitnami/moodle` is gone
# ...
```

... Similarly in the second `docker-compose.yml`

The solution is really simple: put your plugins in the `D:\Docker\Moodle\Moodle\local\local_custom_api`. Also, you could instead of defining the docker file just use the default image in the `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
# db...
  moodle:
    image: bitnami/moodle:latest
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 8443:8443
    environment:
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_HOST=mariadb
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_USER=root
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_PASSWORD=moodle
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_NAME=moodle
    volumes:
      - D:\\Docker\\Moodle\\Moodle:/bitnami/moodle
      - D:\\Docker\\Moodle\\MoodleData:/bitnami/moodledata
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    links:
      - mariadb:mariadb
```

The copying in the docker file has another disadvantage during prototyping, it is just a copy and every time you change anything you must rebuild the container. On the other hand, volumes are "synchronize", they are the same directory visible both from the outside and the inside. So when you have new version of the plugin, you just restart the container.

Using (named) volumes is not necessary, see [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/) for more informations what is the difference to the bind mounts (=using paths).

Comment: Okay I still don't get why the file in `/opt/bitnami/moodle/config.php` is not found because I am not binding to this path or any parent. Also I dont want to put the code in the volume directory directly because the code is part of a code repo. So I have to copy it every time I make changes. That was the idea behind the Dockerfile. Also, I don't have to restart the container when the code is inside the volume directory. Is there a way to create another volume for the source code? `.\\local_aemtec_api:/bitnami/moodle/local/custom_api` leads to a process crash

Comment: Did you ever solve this Marcel? I too am having the same problem. The above answer and below answer do not solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue (also found [this issue](https://github.com/bitnami/containers/issues/28135) which was kind of annoying...).

I did this and it got resolved (taken from [here](https://github.com/accredible/moodle-mod_accredible#optbitnamimoodleconfigphp-no-such-file-or-directory)):

##### /opt/bitnami/moodle/config.php: No such file or directory

The following error is raised if the moodle service has not completed the initial installation:

```
moodle_1      | grep: /opt/bitnami/moodle/config.php: No such file or directory
```

Please make sure if the initial installation has been completed.

If the error keeps happening, it would be better to clear the containers with the following commands:

```
docker-compose down -v
rm -rf .docker/volumes/mariadb/data
```

and set it up again from the beginning.